# Using Named Parameter in native SQL query with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, db2

Was given the below query to run against a DB2 database however it returns below error in my Spring Boot App.

I've researched that `:COL_1_1001` should be some sort of named parameter or host variable(DB2) but have not been able to find a similar example of what I'm trying to do.  I have only ever used `?1` to set a parameter using `@Query` which to my understanding is for JPQL.  Since I'm attempting a native SQL query here, not sure if this should work.

```
@Repository 
public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, EntityID> {

@Query(value="SELECT COL_1"
              + ",COL_2"
              + ",COL_3"
              + "FROM TABLE_A"
              + "WHERE COL_1 = :COL_1_1001", nativeQuery = true)
List<Entity> getEntityDetails();
}
```

> [ERROR]~2019-09-19-07.26.30.347CDT~~~~~
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] Servlet.service() for servlet
>   [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Named
>   parameter not bound : COL; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : COL] with
>   root cause org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound :
>   COL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use variable `COL_1_1001` in your query but do not provide it. You have to add an argument annotated with `@Param` so the value can be injected into query.

Change:

```
@Query(value="SELECT COL_1"
              + ",COL_2"
              + ",COL_3"
              + "FROM TABLE_A"
              + "WHERE COL_1 = :COL_1_1001", nativeQuery = true)
List<Entity> getEntityDetails();
```

to:

```
@Query(value="SELECT COL_1"
              + ",COL_2"
              + ",COL_3"
              + "FROM TABLE_A"
              + "WHERE COL_1 = :col", nativeQuery = true)
List<Entity> getEntityDetails(@Param("col") String col); // it may not be a string - use the actual tyle of COL_1
```

For more info look into [Spring Data documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters)

Comment: please, I have a question can we use the same expression with list of parameters I mean doing this (...WHERE user in (:userCol)) or they are some changes to make?

Answer (score 0):

@Wallwalker, Here you need to pass parameter in query method as expected using @Param annotation.

**Spring-JPA with PostgreSql:**
Some time this error ask to cast field and if not matched then shows.

```
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Named parameter not bound : text;
```

Hence, you need to cast explicitly.
e.g.

```
age::integer=20
OR
CAST('2020-12-22' as DATE)
OR
mob_col1::text=substr(mob_array_col1::text, 1, 10) 
OR
cast(mob_col1 as text)=substr(cast(mob_array_col1 as text), 1, 10)
```

Reference:
[PostgreSql-substr](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/substr-function.php)