# How to pass parameters in a native query JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have service class which receives list of cars by calling JPA repository with `carRepository.retrieveCars()`. Repository method is using native query to retrieves records.

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, String> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
           value = "select *" +
                   "from car_records")
 }
 List<Car> retrieveCars();
```

Now I would like to pass parameters `carRepository.retrieveCars(Long vinNo, Long serialNo)` and use them in a query. I assume that I will need something as a prepared statements. However Im not sure how to implement that.

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<TRace, String> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
           value = "select *" +
                   "from car_records" +
                    "where carVinNo = ?! and carSerialNo >= ?1")
 }
 
 query.setParameter(1, vinNo, 2,serialNo);   //this is certainly not correct implementation
 List<Car> retrieveCars(vinNo, serialNo);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are two ways around that when you use  Spring Data JPA

**1) Named Parameters**

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<TRace, String> {
        @Query(nativeQuery = true,
               value = "select *" +
                       "from car_records" +
                        "where carVinNo = :vinNo and carSerialNo >= :serialNo")
     }
     List<Car> retrieveCars(@Param("vinNo") Long vinNo,@Param("serialNo") Long serialNo); 
    }
```

[spring doc for named parameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters)

**2) Indexed Parameters**

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<TRace, String> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
           value = "select *" +
                   "from car_records" +
                    "where carVinNo = ?1 and carSerialNo >= ?2")
 }
 List<Car> retrieveCars(Long vinNo, Long serialNo); 
}
```

[example for index parameter from spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query.native)

Then from your service class you call it

```
carRepository.retrieveCars(vinNo, serialNo);
```

Both cases will work the same for you.

Comment: why do you say that. It is supposed to work. It is called indexed parameters in query

Comment: If service class will use  `carRepository.retrieveCars(1, 2)` it will be passing int 1 and 2 and that is not what I need. I need to pass   vinNo  and  serialNo  paramenters  from service into query.  Perhaps your first solution might work.
This is from baeldung.com. It should be something like this: 
`TypedQuery<Employee> query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.empNumber = ?1", Employee.class);String empNumber = "A123";Employee employee = query.setParameter(1, empNumber).getSingleResult();`

Comment: We mean the same thing with different words. Your vinNo and serialNo are called variables and when you use them they have actual values. So during execution your vinNo could have value 1 or some other value from service. I didn't know exactly the name of your variables in the service class, therefore I made an example with actual values :D. You could use in your service carRepository.retrieveCars(vinNo, serialNo) and it would be the same .

Comment: Don't change anything in those above solutions. They don't need any adaptation. Just call from your service  carRepository.retrieveCars(vinNo, serialNo) and see it by yourself working.

Comment: I will try 1st solution but I dont really get your 2nd solution. In solution 2  `List<Car> retrieveCars(vinNo, serialNo);` will receive vinNo and  serialNo  parameters. So where are the 1 and 2 in the query coming from ?

Comment: At indexed parameters ?1 means that the query will put the value of the first variable where the ?1 is placed. So it would take the value of the variable carVinNo and put it in the place of ?1. The same applies to ?2. Spring Data JPA will do it for you in the background. Search for indexed parameters in JPA and you will understand

Comment: take my updated version of 1st solution. The previous will also work, but this now is what official spring proposes

Comment: please consider accepting answer if it has solved the problem

Comment: In 2nd sol. it should be  `List<Car> retrieveCars(Long vinNo, Long serialNo);` and its called from service  `carRepository.retrieveCars(vinNo, serialNo)`

Comment: Updated the answer with the parameter types also

Comment: Still doesnt work. Your solution in the documentation doesnt use `nativeQuery = true`. So perhaps its not supposed to work with native  query.

Comment: I think that you make something wrong and therefore it does not work. Have you used @Param()? There is already another accepted answer on stackoverflow indicating that solution 2 should also work for native queries. Check it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58013353/7237884

Comment: above comment meant solution 1 should also work when you said it was not documented by spring

Comment: How to deal with in and out params?

Comment: what if I want to pass in an object as: 
`List<Car> retrieveCars(@Param("myCar") Car myCar);`
would that work?

Comment: @W.Elbashier yes you can pass an object but considering you want to return the same type of entity you would have to make some specific comparison in the query ex `FROM CAR WHERE id=myCar.id`

Comment: Can we change target param type? `@Type("uuid-char") @Param("id") id:UUID` some thing like this. So, that it converts uuid to string on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM db.issuer_details where creation_date between ?1 AND ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    List<MerchantData> dataWithDate(String from ,String to);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.