# Native Query JPA - not replacing parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I got an text[] column type in postgres

I am trying to do this

```
public interface MyUserRepo extends CrudRepository<MyUser, String> {

   @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM my_user x WHERE x.tenant_ids @> ARRAY[':tenantId'] AND x.roles @> ARRAY['driver']", nativeQuery = true)
    Set<MyUser> findDrivers(String tenantId);

}
```

My issue is that the param is not replaces. I guessing it's because of the single quote.

I tried using `@Param("tenant_id")` didn't work.

Also tried with Indexed Parameters like `?1`

Comment: Someone had the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66071165/how-to-pass-parameters-in-a-native-query-jpa

Comment: Have you tried without the single quotes?

Comment: tried , inject the param but query blows 

`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: text[] @> character varying[]
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, you are using a named parameter ":tenantId" in the native SQL query. However, when you're trying to reference it in the array literal, you are using single quotes around the parameter, which is causing the issue. Additionally, the parameter name in the @Param annotation should match the parameter name in the query.

To resolve this issue, you should remove the single quotes around the parameter in the array literal and ensure that the parameter name in the @Param annotation matches the parameter name in the query.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
public interface MyUserRepo extends CrudRepository<MyUser, String> {

   @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM my_user x WHERE x.tenant_ids @> ARRAY[:tenantId] AND x.roles @> ARRAY['driver']", nativeQuery = true)
   Set<MyUser> findDrivers(@Param("tenantId") String tenantId);

}
```

Comment: yeah . Will inject it but query will not work
`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: text[] @> character varying[]   Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: Maybe you should do an explicity cast to the array:
```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM my_user x WHERE x.tenant_ids @> ARRAY[:tenantId]::text[] AND x.roles @> ARRAY['driver']", nativeQuery = true)

Comment: thank you: casting did the magic. Your syntax is wrong, but:  
`@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM my_user t WHERE t.tenant_ids  @> CAST(?1 AS text[])" ,nativeQuery = true)`
(Detail tenant id needs to be between curly brackets)